# Increasing cpu core directly related to performance?

Tags: performance, architecture, cpu-architecture

Simple question, increasing core directly related to performance?

My understanding (kindly correct me if i am wrong) is in multi-core systems, communication overhead and memory 
latencies are a limiting factor in performance as compared to single core. Perhaps a single core system with large L1 and L2 cache can perform much better then Core 2 Duos? But then why in almost every new architecture number of cores are being increased. There must be reason which i am here to know.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally memory latency nor bandwidth are an issues when scaling up the # of cores in a system.  Note: There are probably specialized exceptions, but by and large most modern systems don't start running into memory bottlenecks until 6+ hardware cores are accessing memory.

Communication overhead, however, can be devastatingly expensive.  The technical reasons for this are extremely complicated and beyond the scope of my answer -- some aspects are related to hardware but others are simply related to the cost of one core blocking for another to finish its calculations .. both are bad.  Because of this, programs/applications that utilize multiple cores typically must do so with as little communication between cores as possible.  This limits the types of tasks that can off-loaded onto separate cores.

New systems are adding more cores simply because it is technologically feasible.  Eg, increasing single core performance is neither technically nor economically viable anymore.  Almost all applications programmers I know would absolutely prefer a single ultra-fast core over having to figure out how to efficiently utilize 12 cores.  But the chip manufacturers couldn't produce such a core even if you granted them tens of millions of dollars.

As long as the speed of light is a fixed constant, parallel processing will be here to stay.  As it is today, much of the speed improvement found in CPUs is due to parallel processing of individual instructions.  As much as is possible, a Core 2 Duo (for example) will run up to four instructions in parallel. This works because in many programs sequences of instructions are often not immediately dependent on each other:

1. a = g_Var1 + 1;
2. b = g_Var2 + 3;
3. c = b * a;
4. d = g_Var3 + 5;

Modern CPUs will actually execute lines 1,2, AND 4 in parallel, and then double back and finish up line 3 -- usually in parallel with whatever comes in lines 5,6,etc.  (assuming the 'c' variable result isn't needed in any of them).  This is needed because our ability to speed up or shorten the pipeline for executing any single instruction is very limited.  So instead engineers have been focusing on "going wide" -- more instructions in parallel, more cores in parallel, more computers in parallel (the last being similar to cloud computing, BOINC or @home projects).

Comment: thanks a lot it clears several things!

Comment: I wish i could have gave you more votes :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your software. If you have CPU intensive calculation tasks that don't use much external communication and require parallel processing - multi-core is the way to go to scale vertically. It will perform much better to compare with single core CPU...since it can perform calculation tasks in parallel (again depends on your particular task(s) that take advantage of paralleled execution). For example DB servers usually take advantage of parallel processing and scale greatly on multi-core CPUs.

Once vertical limit exhausted, you can scale horizontally by introducing multiple nodes in your cluster and you would need to coordinate task execution.

So to your question:

> But then why in almost every new architecture number of cores are
>   being increased.

One of the reasons is that software evolves to take advantage of parallel processing and hardware trying to satisfy this hunger.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that cores *can* become usefully more complex. At this point, that's not a safe assumption.

You can either execute more instructions at once ("wider") or pipeline more for higher frequencies ("deeper").

Both of these approaches get diminishing returns. Wider chips rely on parallelism being available at the instruction level, which it largely isn't beyond about 3-wide in the best cases and ~1 typically. Deeper chips have power and heat issues (power typically scales quadraticaly with frequency due to voltage increases, while scaling linearly with core count) and hurt branch mispredict recovery time.

We do multi core chips not because we want to, but because we're out of better alternatives.